# Powershell - Automate website popup

Tags: c#, powershell, automation, messagebox, invocation

I am currently working on an automation project.

Mainly everything is coded in powershell as the project involve AD, Exchange etc.

Last part involves integration to a website to fill a form. I have used `document.getElementByID()` and everything is working perfectly, but when I click the last button: `Approve` a popup shows up:

Window text: Message from webpage
Text: Are you sure?
Buttons: OK, Cancel

My question is, how can I answer a Messagebox generated by website?

I've looked through the DOM Explorer but can only find the Approve button, no child elements or anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is entirely dependant on how the popup is created. It may be created entirely in Javascript for example. Who knows. Without more research and information from you, we can't answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks DavidG, i figured it was all i java.

Found my way through the code and got i all working by simply ignoring the popup message and go directly to next step.